# How to use *.RTF files in WebView?

Tags: swift, rtf

Please, tell me:

How to use (initialize in code) an RTF file in WebView?

And how to use RTF file in Struct\Array like a txt file - (NSString(contentsOfFile: "˜/SomeText.txt", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil). Are it is possible?

I was find many instructions for Objective-C, but can't understand it and use in Swift.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at NSAttributedString. This class provides direct import/export interchange with RTF files.

For iOS, the reference you want is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html

For OS X, the reference you want is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/

Comment: The links are dead.